# Php log and floor function strange behavior

Tags: php, logging, floor

My problem is the following:
`log(1000,10)` returns `3`, but `floor(log(1000,10))` returns `2`. How to fix this issue?

My phpversion is 5.6.30-0+deb8u1.

Comment: Interesting: https://3v4l.org/CemOL.

Comment: @localheinz Wtf... did you just find a bug? I mean, on the manual of PHP there's nothing written that the function has changed for PHP7+ - http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

Comment: @Twinfriends No idea, to be honest!

Comment: whooa that's strange

Comment: Try this one to get bananas: https://3v4l.org/KVCol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From a 13 year old comment at the PHP:log documentation:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php)

```
$val = 1000000
$val2 = floor(log($val,10)) // gives a value of 5 for $val2 and not 6 as expected.
$val2 = floor(log10($val)) // gives the correct value.
```

So you should use `floor(log10(1000);`

While I'm certainly no expert, I think the different outcome in PHP5 and PHP7 (as pointed out in the comments on your question) has to do with [scalar type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php), a new feature in PHP 7 (try playing with strict mode to find out more, eg. https://3v4l.org/KVCol).

Answer (score 6):

Because `log(1000)` is something like 2.9999999999999996 and the floor() function rounds a number DOWN to the nearest integer

if you want to have 3, use round and not floor

Comment: True. The type of the result will still be float, just as additional note.

Comment: I have to use the exponent in the normal form of the integer, so I can't use round (for 999 I have to return 2)

Comment: you can always check if it's really close to the next number.

Answer (score -1):

It may related to float precision. You can use log10(1000) instead.

Comment: why vote me down? Please try log10(1000) and return a real 3